# Why is this function returning an empty list even though I am using a for loop/the append method?

Tags: python, list, function

I am trying to learn how functions and for loops work but don't understand what's going on. I am creating a function, and in the function is a local variable `emptylist` that stores the values of everything inside `inputByUser`. But everytime I print it's giving me 0. Please help me out.

For example if I type in 15 it SHOULD give me [1....15]. Instead it gives me [0] wtf?

```
inputbyUser = int(input('Enter an integer value.'))

def loops(inputbyUser):
    emptylist = []
    for i in range(inputbyUser + 1):
        emptylist.append(i)
        return emptylist


dictT = loops(inputbyUser)
print(dictT)
```

Comment: You should remove 4 spaces before `return emptylist`.

Comment: please provide context/explanation @sanyash

Comment: `return` returns from the function.

Answer (score 1):

The return instruction is in the for loop. Hence, on the first value in the 
for loop, you directly return the array with the value 0.

Try this

```
inputbyUser = int(input('Enter an integer value.'))

def loops(inputbyUser):
    emptylist = []
    for i in range(inputbyUser + 1):
        emptylist.append(i)
    return emptylist

dictT = loops(inputbyUser)
print(dictT)
```

Comment: Can you provide further context/explanation. What do you mean on the first value in the loop I return the value 0 in the array?

Comment: What the code does is basically calling the `loops` function.
Once in there, a list is created and then comes the `for` loop. 
In the `for` loop, the first value (0) is added to the list and the list is returned.
So, the list contains only one value when it is return. 
The `return` has to be out of the for loop